# Safari Extension Fails to perform URLSession Tasks with error: failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Operation not permitted

Tags: swift, xcode, safari, safari-extension

Hi guys I attempts to make RESTful call when toolbar item is click.
then it fails to connect to the internet with the following error in log.

```
[default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
The extension's toolbar item was clicked
dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:5 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
Error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600003e3c4b0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://some_valid_url, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://some_valid_url, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.})
[] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C1] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)
TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x60000051d200]: 10:-72000 Err(-65563)
Task <D9356F42-2832-426A-9FE6-C37C0A22F954>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [10:-72000])
Task <D9356F42-2832-426A-9FE6-C37C0A22F954>.<1> finished with error - code: -1003
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

So then I tried:

- Turn on App sandbox and tick both incoming and outgoing connection

  - Does not work, same error
- Turn off App sandbox

  - Extension disappears in safari preferences
  - No response when I click "Open in Safari Extensions Preferences"

My config:

- Xcode: Version 10.1 (10B61)
- Mac: Mojave 10.14.2（18C54）
- Safari: 12.0.2（14606.3.4）

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable Incoming and Outgoing connections on the app Sandbox to let your requests go thru.

[image: Check this image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I did try what you suggested. It does not work.

Comment: Did you enabled it on all targets ? Also, you may need to add the domain you are trying to access under SFSafariWebsiteAccess Key in the Info.plist of your extension